# How to include the optgroup containing the chosen option when submitting a form?

Tags: php, forms, optgroup

```
<?php $kategorie = $pdo->prepare("SELECT kategorie FROM tdgm_kategorien");
        $kategorie->execute(array()); ?>
<select name="rubrik" id="where" class="input">
    <?php while($r = $kategorie->fetch()) { 
   $kat = $r['kategorie']; ?>
    <optgroup label="<?= htmlspecialchars($r['kategorie'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') ?>" 
              value="<?= htmlspecialchars($r['kategorie'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') ?>">
        <?php $rubrik = $pdo->prepare("SELECT rubrik FROM ".$r['kategorie']."");
        $rubrik->execute(array());?>
        <?php while($e = $rubrik->fetch()) { ?>
        <option class="option" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($e['rubrik'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') ?>">
            <?= htmlspecialchars($e['rubrik'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') ?> </option><?php } ?></optgroup><?php } ?>
</select>
```

How can I pass the corresponding value of an optgroup to a script according to the option chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`optgroup` has no `value` attribute. But you can prepend the `optgroup` value to the `option` seperated by something like `::`. Then on the server, you split the value by `::` to get both the `$kategorie` and the `$rubrik`.

HTML

```
<?php 
    $kategorie = $pdo->prepare("SELECT kategorie FROM tdgm_kategorien");
    $kategorie->execute(array()); ?>
    <select name="rubrik" id="where" class="input">
        <?php while($r = $kategorie->fetch()) { 
            $kat = htmlspecialchars($r['kategorie'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>
            <optgroup label="<?= $kat ?>">
                <?php $rubrik = $pdo->prepare("SELECT rubrik FROM ".$r['kategorie']."");
                $rubrik->execute(array());?>

                <?php while($e = $rubrik->fetch()) {
                    $rub = htmlspecialchars($e['rubrik'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') ?>
                    <option class="option" value="<?= $kat.'::'.$rub ?>"><?= $rub ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </optgroup>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
?>
```

SERVER

```
<?php

$exp = explode('::', $_POST['rubrik'] ?? '');
$kategorie = $exp[0] ?? '';
$rubrik = $exp[1] ?? '';
```